# AddInExpress install error - AddCustomTaskPanes

Tags: .net, vsto, excel-addins, customtaskpane

When I install a AddInExpress addin and open Excel I get this error:

```
Exception Source:      
Exception Type:        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Exception Message:     Unable to create specified ActiveX control.
Exception Target Site: ForwardCallToInvokeMember

---- Stack Trace ----
   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(memberName As String, flags As BindingFlags, target As Object, aWrapperTypes As Int32[], msgData As MessageData&)
       mscorlib.dll: N 0202 (0xCA) IL 
   AddinExpress.MSO.ICTPFactory.CreateCTP(CTPAxID As String, CTPTitle As String, CTPParentWindow As Object)
       mscorlib.dll: N 00000 (0x0) JIT 
   AddinExpress.MSO.ADXAddinModule.AddCustomTaskPanes(parent As Object, outlookFolderName As String)
       mscorlib.dll: N 0000 (0x0) IL
```

Searching the web there is only one other article: http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=2355 and that isn't applicable because I have a higher version.

Does anyone know how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to help out others in the future.

I had to change the Name of the TaskPane:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my last item of the application namespace was "Word". My full control ame was "TermLynx.Word.UserControl." After refactoring my project to use "TermLynx.WordAddin" instead of "TermLynx.Word", the problem vanish.